# Google Script - Running on Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am wanting to deploy a Google Script project from a Google Document where the text from the Google Doc is displayed to a particular region of an index.html file. Is there any way to do so? I would be very curious to learn.

```
<html>
<h1> Header </h1>
[Google Document Code Goes Here.]
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to maintain all of the formatting?

Comment: Yes, all of it. It doesn't have to be spaced out the same way though.

Comment: That will be a fair amount of work even if you know what you're doing.  You might want to look for some addons that already exist.  I don't know of any because I never use them.

Comment: Even just part of it would be helpful. I understand.

Comment: It's pretty simple if you don't want the format.  You can get the body text and put it into a textarea.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do! How would you do that? I specifically want it inside a text area box. So, that would work out really well. How do you get the body text? I haven't dealt with Google Script with docs that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple dialog that displays the text from a google document to a textarea tag in an html dialog.

```
function displaytestintextarea() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const text = body.getText();
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<textarea row="25" cols="50">${text}</textarea>`),"Text in TextArea");
}
```

In this situation it's not required to provide the entire html.

[image]

You can resize it to anysize you wish.